# How does clickhouse perform regular matching

Tags: clickhouse

extractAll ( now_url, '.*?ActivityJunBCJ&a=payment(|M)&id=(\d+)(&.*?){0,}&fromTypes=(\d+)(&.*?){0,}')；

like this,how does regexp extract to get fromtype?

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an escape character in CH strings, you need double them to screen it. `\\`

```
SELECT extractAllGroups('abc=123, 8="hkl"', '("[^"]+"|\\w+)=("[^"]+"|\\w+)');


extractAll (row,'\\\\[[\\\\d]+,"([\\\\w]+)",[\\\\d]+,[\\\\d]+,[\\\\d]+,[\\\\d]+\\\\]'),
```